# How to read less variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, maven, less

I am working on a project that all of the less variables are compiled to Css by Maven. There is lots of variables for colours in the less file. I want to have access to these colour variables from javascript. In that case I can define the colours once and use it in css and javascript.

Could anyone please help me with introducing a Maven plugin or a method to read the less variables in Javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code snippet explaining how to access less variables in JavaScript

```js
// getLessVars :: https://gist.github.com/2948738
/**
 * getLessVars parses your LESS variables to Javascript (provided you make a dummy node in LESS)
 * @param {String} id The CSS-id your variables are listed under.
 * @param {Boolean} [parseNumbers=true] Try to parse units as numbers.
 * @return {Object} A value object containing your LESS variables.
 * @example
 * LESS:
 *  &#64;myLessVariable: 123px;
 *  #dummyLessId { width: @myLessVariable; }
 * Javascript:
 *  getLessVars('dummyLessId');
 * returns:
 *  {myLessVariable:123}
 */
function getLessVars(id,parseNumbers) {
 var bNumbers = parseNumbers===undefined?true:parseNumbers
  ,oLess = {}
  ,rgId = /\#[\w-]+/
  ,rgKey = /\.([\w-]+)/
  ,rgUnit = /[a-z]+$/
  ,aUnits = 'em,ex,ch,rem,vw,vh,vmin,cm,mm,in,pt,pc,px,deg,grad,rad,turn,s,ms,Hz,kHz,dpi,dpcm,dppx'.split(',')
  ,rgValue = /:\s?(.*)\s?;\s?\}/
  ,rgStr = /^'([^']+)'$/
  ,sId = '#'+id
  ,oStyles = document.styleSheets;
 for (var i=0,l=oStyles.length;i<l;i++) {
  var oRules;
  try{ oRules = oStyles[i].cssRules; }
  catch (e) { continue; }
  if (oRules) {
   for (var j=0,k=oRules.length;j<k;j++) {
    try { var sRule = oRules[j].cssText; }
    catch (e) { continue; }
    var aMatchId = sRule.match(rgId);
    if (aMatchId&&aMatchId[0]==sId) {
     var aKey = sRule.match(rgKey)
      ,aVal = sRule.match(rgValue);
     if (aKey&&aVal) {
      var sKey = aKey[1]
       ,oVal = aVal[1]
       ,aUnit
       ,aStr;
      if (bNumbers&&(aUnit=oVal.match(rgUnit))&&aUnits.indexOf(aUnit[0])!==-1) {
       oVal = parseFloat(oVal);
      } else if (aStr=oVal.match(rgStr)) {
       oVal = aStr[1];
      }
      oLess[sKey] = oVal;
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return oLess;
}


// parse less
less.refresh();

// read variables from id #foobar
var oVars = getLessVars('foobar'),
    mPre = document.createElement('pre'),
    sData = "\n";
for (var s in oVars) sData += "\t" + s + ': ' + oVars[s] + "\n";
mPre.innerHTML = sData;
document.body.appendChild(mPre);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
<style type="text/less">
    
    // less variables
    @myWidth: 200px;
    @myPadding: 5px;
    @myBorderColor: #666;
    
    // add variables as classes to a non-existing id
    #foobar {
        .myWidth { width: @myWidth; }
        .myPadding { width: @myPadding; }
        .myBorderColor { color: @myBorderColor; }
    }
    
    // variables usage
    div {
        width: @myWidth;
        padding: @myPadding;
        border: 2px solid @myBorderColor;
    }
    
</style>
</head><body>
<div>this div uses the following less properties:</div>
</body></html>
```

You can also refer https://gist.github.com/Sjeiti/2948738

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am working on a big project that all of the less files are compiled to CSS before rendering the HTML. So I can not have access to the less variables in the HTML. I am looking for a solution that via Maven read the less files and automatically generate a json file, then maybe I can read it from javascript. I do not know if it is a good solution or there is easier way to do it. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Less can be used on the client as well. Reading from their documentation:

> Client-side Usage
>   Using less.js in the browser is great for development, but it's not recommended for production
>   Client-side is the easiest way to get started and good for developing with Less, but in production, when performance and reliability is important, we recommend pre-compiling using node.js or one of the many third party tools available.
>
> To start off, link your .less stylesheets with the rel attribute set to "stylesheet/less":

`<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />`

> Next, download less.js and include it in a  tag in the  element of your page:

> Tips
>
> Make sure you include your stylesheets before the script.
>   When you link more than one .less stylesheet each of them is compiled independently. So any variables, mixins or namespaces you define in a stylesheet are not accessible in any other.
>   Due to the same origin policy of browsers loading external resources requires enabling CORS
>
> Less CDN

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.7.2/less.min.js"></script>`

Defined variables can be found in `less` `data` or trough `less.Parser` or various API.

For some `Parser` sample see: [get variables values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11827453/less-js-get-variable-values-inside-parsers-callback)